# Can I reduce a an 21 page postscript file to a 3 page postscript file?

Tags: printing, resize, graphviz, postscript

I have a postscript file that is printed on 21 pages (it is a 3 x 7 page drawing).

Now, I'd like to scale the output by 1/3rd (or 1/9th...) so that the entire drawing is 1 page wide and 3 (=floor(7/3)) pages high.

Is there a possibility to achieve what I want?

I am on Windows, and have GhostView installed, if this information should influence the answer.

Also, the post script was created with dot/graphviz, maybe there is something in the *.dot file that I could change?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot language has a graph attribute called `size` for specifying the maximum width and height of the output, in inches. If it's too big to fit in that space, it gets scaled down to fit.

So I think to make it one page wide and three pages high, assuming the pages are portrait, you could set the `size` attribute's width to the width of a page in inches (if you're using American Letter size, I think that's 8 1/2 inches, or A4 is 8.3 inches), and the height 3 times the height of a page (or larger)

Example (I think this works!)

```
graph G {
    graph [size="1.0,1.5"]
    Foo -- Bar
    Bar -- Baz
}
```

Answer (score 0):

psutils is a classic unix tool but it looks like it's ported to win32: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/psutils.htm

google for example of how to use it